# Gson: set date formatter for timestamp and timezone

Tags: java, android, gson

What pattern should I use for date format 1418805300000-0100 ? (Timestamp and timezone)

```
GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("?????????????-Z")
```

**Solution:**

1. create new GSON with adapters

   ```
   private static Gson createGson(){
   return new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping()
           .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Date.class, new DateTimeSerializer())
           .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Date.class, new DateTimeDeserializer())
           .create();
   }


   public static MyClass fromJson(String json) {
       return createGson().fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
   }

   public  String toJson() {
       return createGson().toJson(this);
   }
   ```
2. JSON Serializer

   ```
   private static class DateTimeSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date> {
       @Override
       public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
           //  hodgie code
           return new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime() + new SimpleDateFormat("Z").format(src));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Deserializer

   ```
   private static class DateTimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

       @Override
       public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
       // hodgie code
       return new Date(Long.valueOf((json).getAsString().substring(0, 13)));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What are those milliseconds? If they are a timestamp, why do you need a timezone?

Comment: yes, this is timestamp, I'll correct my question. Timestamp with timezone – this is the response from server. I can't to modify it.

Comment: (If it's a timestamp, it doesn't need a timezone.)

Comment: you can see oracle site: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081

"TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE is a variant of TIMESTAMP that includes a time zone offset or time zone region name in its value."

Answer (score 1):

`GsonBuilder#setDateFormat(String)` uses the `String` provided as an argument for creating `SimpleDateFormat` instances. `SimpleDateFormat` does not provide any patterns for generating a timestamp. You won't be able to achieve what you want with `setDateFormat`. A custom `TypeAdapter` seems appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I know about adapters. I wrote the example code (see in original post), it works for me. Thanks for the answer.